# Problem trying to add Object to ObservableCollection

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin

I am litle stuck here.

So this is my class that i initialize my `ObservableCollection`:

```
public class ServicosMenu : BindableObject
{
    private Rota _oldSer;

    public  AppService lo = new AppService();
    public ObservableCollection<Rota> ListSer { get; set; }
    public ObservableCollection<Rota> OneSer { get; set; }//foi introduido pra testar 1 so servico
    public List<Rota> y = new List<Rota>();
    public RssRotas rts = new RssRotas();
    public CalendarPopUp cal = new CalendarPopUp();

    public ServicosMenu()
    {
        rts.data = cal.datacal;
        GetListSerAsync();
        ListSer = new ObservableCollection<Rota>();
        OneSer = new ObservableCollection<Rota>();
    }

    public void settt(string value)
    {
        rts.data = value;
    }.....
```

And in the other class this is the code:

```
[XamlCompilation(XamlCompilationOptions.Compile)]
public partial class Servicos : ContentPage
{
    public Servicos (string data)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    public void ListView_ItemTapped(object sender, ItemTappedEventArgs e)
    {
        var vm = BindingContext as ServicosMenu;
        var ser = e.Item as Rota;

        vm.HideOrShowService(ser);
        vm.OneSer.Add(ser); //this is where it gives me the error 
    }

    private async Task Button_Clicked_DetalhesAsync(object sender, ItemTappedEventArgs e)
    {
        await Navigation.PushAsync(new Detalhes());
    }
```

So my problem is that the `ObservableCollection` is doing a "reset" every time I call the view Details, because it has `BindingContext` to the class ServicoMenu. So every time I call the view, it calls the constructor and it initialize again the collection and I lost the value that I was trying to add.

How can I fix this so it do not "reset" the value?

Thanks for any help!!

**EDIT1:**

[image]

As you can see my view class Detalhes already got the value of the item selected, the think is to bind with the xaml listview.
This is my xaml:

[image]

And in the app nothing...[image]

**EDIT2:**

[image]
[image]

and when i touch the button to go to the details page on the app, it do not work and i get this strange think in the output: [image]

Comment: Can you show the details of the exception?

Comment: @Ian i now see that the exception was because of other think and is not showing anymore. But it steel "reset" de coolection because the view is binding the ServicoMenu class and is like calling the constructor again and it "cleans" de Observable collection. Im going to edit my question up

Comment: Is your `ServicosMenu` class a window/control `datacontext` class or is it a helper class that you are calling? This is important since if it is a helper class, it is not static so it is getting picked up by the garbage collector. Please post how you are accessing this class since what you posted does not really show what is needed to fully answer your question.

Comment: I agree with David you need to post a bit more of your code or answer his question on how you are accessing the class in order for us to be able to work out what is the issue.

Comment: ObservableCollection with services that came from a webservice. I really think that my problem now is to bind the item that i selected to the listview in my xaml view. I will edit up for you to see.

Comment: @Tiagodias where are you setting the `BindingContext` of your `Detalhes` class? I can see some commented out XAML which wouldn't work as you expect if uncommented because it would create a new instance of `ServicosMenu`.

Comment: Yes i understand that the commented XAML from the ServicoMenu would "reset" everytime i call the view soo i try too bind the Details class but always happen some problem like this now(EDIT2 up), getting this on the output trying to bind the class Detalhes too his own view.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Damm, it was hard to understand this, what i did was just 2 things diferent from the EDIT2 up in the question.

1º - I just switch this line in c# class of Detalhes : BindingContext = Rote; (and put it after the "InitializeComponent();" )

2º - in the XAML page of Detalhes, in the part that i have the " ItemsSource="{Binding **Name**}" it actually work just with the dot, like this:  ItemsSource="{Binding **.**}"

@Bijington, @Ian, @David thanks for the help trying to work this in my head, it maybe nothing of the other world for most experience programmers but i´m just now enter the job market and getting to understand the all dynamicof the xamarin.